# store multiple of float type on EEPROM

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom

I have 7 float variables.

`float temperature, differential, calibration,hta,lta,hha,lha;`

I want to store them all on the EEPROM memory, how do I calculate the addresses given that there type is float.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

create a struct and store the struct

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

const int DATA_ADDR = 0;

struct MyData {
  float temperature, differential, calibration,hta,lta,hha,lha;
};

MyData data;

void setup() {
  data.temperature = 1.2;

  EEPROM.put(DATA_ADDR, data);

  EEPROM.get(DATA_ADDR, data);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `sizeof` function:

```
int nrOfBytesOfTemperature = sizeof(temperature);
```

You can also use directly a type:

```
int nrOfBytesOfFloat = sizeof(float);
```